# What's the difference between these two ways of incrementing pointers for a 2D array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I'm pretty new to C, and this is my first question here, so I hope I can be clear with my problem.

I wrote a function that applies a filter to a .bmp image. Inside the function I allocated memory through **malloc()** to store every pixel with the new value. After I finish, I want to assign the new values to the original pixels through pointers. I tried two ways of doing this, one works and the other doesn't, but I don't understand the difference.

Here I declare the two pointers:

```
RGBTRIPLE *copy = malloc(height * width * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)); //RGBTRIPLE is the pixel struct
if (copy == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation error\n");
    exit(2);
}
RGBTRIPLE *rgb = &image[0][0]; // this points to first element of original image
```

Here are the two methods I tried for assigning the new values. The following doesn't 
    work:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < (height * width); i++)
{
    *rgb = *copy;
    rgb++;
    copy++;     
}
free(copy);
return;
```

This one does work:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < (height * width); i++)
{
    *((RGBTRIPLE *)rgb + i) = *((RGBTRIPLE *)copy + i);
}
free(copy);
return;
```

Why?

Answer (score 2):

For any pointer or array `p` and index `i`, the expression `*(p + i)` is *exactly* equal to `p[i]`.

That means your second loop really does

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < (height * width); i++)
{
    rgb[i] = copy[i];
}
```

I believe that the version above is more clear about what's happening and why it works.

---

The problem with the first loop is that you ***modify*** both `rgb` and `copy`, so you loose the original pointers. You need to use temporary pointers for it to work:

```
int i;
RGBTRIPLE *temp_rgb = rgb;
RGBTRIPLE *temp_copy = copy;
for (i = 0; i < (height * width); i++)
{
    *temp_rgb = *temp_copy;
    temp_rgb++;
    temp_copy++;     
}

// Here the original values of rgb and copy still exists
```

Comment: How is it he is modifying copy? All he does is copy the contents of the copy item to the contents of the rib item. No?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle `copy++` is basically `copy = copy + 1`. So `copy` is modified. Note that I didn't say that the data pointed to by `copy` is modified, only the variable `copy` itself.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude "For any pointer or array p and index i, ..." this is not the case for `void *`  It should be "For any `typed` pointer or array ...."

Comment: @Landstalker Considering the "or array" part, and the second half of the sentence, the context of "any pointer" is implied to be "any dereferencable pointer".

Answer (score 1):

In the first code, when you reach here :

```
free(copy);
```

`copy` has been modified, so it's invalid to try to `free` it. You need to free the original pointer as returned by `malloc`.